# Does HCatalog require installation before being used?

Tags: hadoop, hcatalog

Can anyone please tell me that, does HCatalog require installation before using? Or it can be used just as a jar file?

I have Cloudera running on a VM, and I can use HCatalog for my MR job, Pig, Hive with no problem. And I thought the same MR code would work with another hadoop installed platform, but obviously it's not the case, exception thrown on the HCatInputFormat.setInput(). When I use `Pig -useHCatalog`, I'ved been prompted that the usage was wrong, meaning that it didn't know what's `-useHCatalog` as a parameter.

Didn't thought about this before as have been using HCatalog on Cloudera...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to install and start HCatalog server. HCatalog should come with the latest Hive tar package.

Check here of [Apache Hive documentation](http://hive.apache.org/docs/hcat_r0.5.0/install.html) for details,

Basically you need to,

1. Setup MySQL database for HCatalog
2. Run server install script

   share/hcatalog/scripts/hcat_server_install.sh -r root -d dbroot -h
   hadoop_home -p portnum
3. Start the HCatalog server

   export HIVE_HOME=hive_home
   $HIVE_HOME/sbin/hcat_server.sh start

Comment: Thanks. Because I am testing something in DataStax, but they have all Hive, Pig, etc. 1 to couple verions older than the most updated... thinking how can I use the HCatalog in that case.

Comment: HCatalog has been moved into Hive after 26 Mar. 2013, HCatalog release 0.5, check [here](http://hive.apache.org/hcatalog/index.html). Now HCatalog release number should follow Hive. The latest one is 0.12.0.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, you do not need to install hcatalog separately if you are working with hive 0.12 or later versions.